# QStyleSheet - setting border-image for button also sets background image for its tooltip

Tags: qt, pyqt, tooltip, qstylesheet, qtoolbutton

I'm having a problem with setting the `border-image` property of a `QToolButton` (later on also of a `QPushButton` but I assume the problem will occur there too). Each of my custom buttons (inheriting from `QToolButton` and `QPushButton` respectively) has to have 3 states - inactive, running and error.

**Inactive:**

```
style = 'border-top-right-radius: ' + str(self.cornerRadius) + 'px; border-bottom-right-radius: ' + str(self.cornerRadius) + 'px; border-top-left-radius: ' + str(self.cornerRadius) + 'px; border-bottom-left-radius: ' + str(self.cornerRadius) + 'px; border-image: url("' + self.icon  + '"); background: none;'
```

**Running:**

```
style = 'border-top-right-radius: ' + str(self.cornerRadius) + 'px; border-bottom-right-radius: ' + str(self.cornerRadius) + 'px; border-top-left-radius: ' + str(self.cornerRadius) + 'px; border-bottom-left-radius: ' + str(self.cornerRadius) + 'px; border-image: url("' + self.icon  + '"); background: rgb(89, 205, 139);'
```

**Error:**

```
style = 'border-top-right-radius: ' + str(self.cornerRadius) + 'px; border-bottom-right-radius: ' + str(self.cornerRadius) + 'px; border-top-left-radius: ' + str(self.cornerRadius) + 'px; border-bottom-left-radius: ' + str(self.cornerRadius) + 'px; border-image: url("' + self.icon  + '"); background: rgb(215, 56, 56);'
```

where `self.cornerRadius` is some number used to determine the roundness of my buttons in pixels and `self.icon` is an icon I have retrieved from somewhere.

All I do in my button's constructor (among other simple initializations) is

```
self.setStyleSheet(style)
```

The `clicked()` signal of the button is connected to a slot in the same class where the state is changed (along with the style using `self.setStyleSheet(...)`) in respect to what the system's new state is.

For some unknown reason my tooltip receives the style changes of the button it "belongs to":

[image]

I've double-checked the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtooltip) and I see no reason that will explain this behaviour. I do NOT want to change the tooltip's style at all. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret the question as:

> How to avoid overlapping the style intended for one widget type with
>   another?

Mind that:

- The stylesheet is propagated from parent to child widgets.
- The stylesheet has visibility you can explicitly set for the type.

  ---

  `myObj.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border: 0.05em solid lightgray;}" )`

Just enclose the stylesheet with the type e.g. `QType { ... }`.

I deal only with C++ Qt but think that PyQt uses same stylesheet system.

Comment: *facepalm* I completely forgot about the parent-child propagation for stylesheets. Thanks for pointing that out and also for broadening the answer to cover the general case.
PS: It's the same for Qt C++ when done in PyQt in terms of stylesheet.